# Trigger Notifications on log in, django

Tags: django, notifications, alerts

Hi Guys I am working on a django project, I have my notifications Model :

```
class Notification(models.Model):
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
kpi = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
site_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

for the moment I have it set up in the action of adding KPIs and it works fine, I would like to change it that it checks for kpi values in my database table : SiteKPIS :

```
class SiteKPIs(models.Model):
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
staff = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
dl = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
idl = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
total_hc = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
total_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
total_out = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
staff_rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
dl_rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
idl_rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
turn_over = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And for example if there is a site that has turn_over<1 it adds a notification.
Can someone guide me through that ? much appreciated

Comment: Would you like the notifications to come periodically or because of an event?

Comment: Hello @DruhinBala, and thank you for your reply,
I would like the notification to come as soon as there is a change in the DB table (SiteKPIs).
But even just on login would be fine